# Waiting to return main block until its encapsulated children are finished

Tags: swift, rest, asynchronous, network-programming

I'm quite new to asynchronous networking in Swift, and am currently using the [SwiftHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) library to run HTTP GET requests.

I've found myself in a situation whereby I run a for loop within an asynchronous GET block, which itself contains a 'secondary'/child GET block, as follows:

```
 request.GET("https://", parameters: nil, success: { (response: HTTPResponse) in
        if response.responseObject != nil {

            var returnArray = [returnObject]() // ***

            // responseObject is an array of 'results', thus loop through and perform a secondary GET for each 'result'

                    for result in response.responseObject {

                        secondaryRequest.GET(result["url"], parameters: nil, success: { (secondaryResponse: HTTPResponse) in
                            if secondaryResponse.responseObject != nil {

                                // *** add secondary repsonseObject to main 'returnArray', created at the top of the first block
                                returnArray.append(secondaryResponse.responseObject!)

                            }


                            },failure: {(error: NSError, secondaryResponse: HTTPResponse?) in
                                println("got an error: \(error)")
                        })

                    }


                completion(returnArray) // HOW TO ONLY RETURN WHEN ALL SECONDARY LOOPS HAVE FINISHED ADDING TO THE RETURN ARRAY???

            }

        }

        }, failure: {(error: NSError, reponse: HTTPResponse?) in
            println("got an error: \(error)")
    })
```

Hopefully it is clear enough that each secondary block adds to a `returnArray` that the main block returns as its completion handler. However, I wish for the main block to execute this completion (and the corresponding array) only when all secondary blocks have finished returning/adding to the `returnArray`.

I don't really know where to start without performing my own hacky options (like, waiting with an NSTimer —I can hear the sighs at that one! :') , or adding each secondary iteration to an external function that counts each addition until it gets to predefined loop threshold).

Many thanks for any and all guidance!

Comment: BTW, do you care about the order that the `returnObject` objects (note, in the future, I'd advise starting class names with uppercase letter) appear in the `returnArray`? My suggestion below answers the question of how to (a) let these run concurrently; and (b) notify you when they're done, but it makes no assurances regarding the order that they're completed. If order is important, rather than using an array, you might use a dictionary or something like that, where you can correlate the order of the objects in the first array.

Comment: Is it thread-safe to use returnArray this way? Seems to me it may get mutated from multiple threads.

Comment: @Rob, I didn't need them to run in order so it's all good. However, can you shed light on @Joe's question about thread safety? Not sure how to stop unnecessary mutations (if it is indeed thread unsafe)... Also, to tag another question; do you happen to have any ideas as to how I could limit the amount of concurrent dispatch_group_enters? I ask due to API limits that I may breach eventually if say, more than 10 `secondaryRequest`s are created, i.e. only allow 5 simultaneously, while queueing a 6th...Nth... Thanks!

Comment: Regarding thread-safety, Joe is right. I assumed this SwiftHTTP ran its completion blocks on the main queue (as Alamofire does), but it doesn't, so you'll have to synchronize the updates the the array yourself (e.g. create a synchronization queue or dispatch those updates to the main queue, like I did below).

Comment: Regarding constraining the number of concurrent requests, the fact that this class uses `NSOperation` makes this much easier. A pull request was  merged today, which remedies some `NSOperation` issues, making this possible.  Bottom line, create your own queue, specify `maxConcurrentOperationCount`, and then use SwiftHTTP's `create` method to create operations which you can then add to that queue.

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing this up. Amazing that you were able to issue a successful pull-request, too: an example of how awesome the community is. Very much appreciate you helping me solve this at such lengths!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger a block of code upon the completion of a series of asynchronous tasks, we generally use "dispatch groups." So create a dispatch group, "enter" the group before every request, "leave"'in every completion block, and then create a dispatch "notify" block that will be called when all of the "enter" calls are balanced by a "leave" call:

```
request.GET("https://", parameters: nil, success: { response in
    if response.responseObject != nil {
        let group = dispatch_group_create()
        var returnArray = [ReturnObject]()

        for result in response.responseObject {
            dispatch_group_enter(group)
            secondaryRequest.GET(result["url"], parameters: nil, success: { secondaryResponse in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    if secondaryResponse.responseObject != nil {
                        returnArray.append(secondaryResponse.responseObject!)
                    }
                    dispatch_group_leave(group)
                }
            },failure: { error, secondaryResponse in
                println("got an error: \(error)")
                dispatch_group_leave(group)
            })
        }

        dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            completion(returnArray)
        }
    }
}, failure: {error, reponse in
    println("got an error: \(error)")
})
```

Note, since `GET` completion handler closures happen on background queues, you need to synchronize the handling of the `returnArray`. You can create a custom queue to coordinate this, or just use the main queue, as I did above.

Comment: Many thanks, clearly need to check-up on this amazing piece of GCD! You saved me a lot of fruitless hours!